# Does an entity bean (ejb 3.x) required container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Is it possible to run entity bean without container? If so example please.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440421

Comment: Note that an EJB entity bean is NOT the same as a JPA entity.

Answer (score 3):

JPA can be used outside of a Java EE container, yes. The specification of JPA2 starts with these words:

> This document is the specification of the Java API for the management of persistence and object/relational mapping with Java EE **and Java SE**.

(emphasis mine)

You won't have automatic support for persistence unit injection, JTA support, etc, though. Spring helps in this area.

Comment: Thanks  @JB Nizet the following post helps me lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419223/can-jpa-2-0-be-used-without-javaee-6?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The main differences with running inside container are definition of persistence-unit and handling transactions.
For an example, persistence-unit is defined as follows, in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu_name" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Then you will need to obtain EntityTransaction and use it:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu_name");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
...
...
tx.commit();

em.close();
emf.close();
```